# Concatenate string and float

Tags: odoo

Is it possible in openerp v7 to output an amount of money with a Euro symbol added in front of it?

If I try, for example, `'€ ' + 0.0` it says I can't append a float to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with **monetary** widget. We are using this for ages.

In python file:

```
class your_class(orm.Model):
    _inherit = 'your.class'

    def _get_your_currency_id(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
        res = {}
        for voucher in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            your_currency_id = self.pool.get('res.currency').search(cr, uid, [('name', '=', 'EUR')], context=context)
            if your_currency_id:
                res[voucher.id] = your_currency_id[0] 
        return res

    _columns = {
                'your_amount_field' :fields.float('Your Amount Field'),
                'your_currency_id': fields.function(_get_your_currency_id, type='many2one', relation='res.currency', string='Currency', readonly=True, required=True),
                }
```

In xml file:

```
<field name="your_currency_id" invisible="1" />
<field name="your_amount_field" class="oe_inline" string="Test Amount" widget="monetary" options="{'currency_field': 'your_currency_id'}" />
```

Technically what it does is, we already have a bunch of all possibly available countries currencies in the table called **res_currency**.

We are just searching for the Euro and letting know the monetary widget to use the particular searched Euro currency using options dictionary. The rest will be taken care by the widget itself.

Answer (score 0):

You just only add widget to the amount field in which you want the currency symbol,

```
<field name="your_field" widget="monetary" options="{'currency_field': 'currency_field_of_you_model'}"
```

Here in options you need to provide currency field available into your model, so it will display the symbol of currency which is belongs to particularly that record or you can put static currency id there then it will show a common symbol in each case.